# Convert UTF-8 Unicode string to ASCII Unicode escaped String

Tags: java, string, unicode, utf-8, ascii

I need to convert unicode string to string which have non-ascii characters encoded in unicode. For example, string "漢字 Max" should be presented as "\u6F22\u5B57 Max".

What I have tried:

1. Differenct combinations of

   new String(sourceString.getBytes(encoding1), encoding2)
2. Apache StringEscapeUtils which escapes also ascii chars like double-quote

   StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(source)

Is there an easy way to encode such string? Ideally only Java 6 SE or Apache Commons should be used to achieve desired result.

Comment: Any reason not to just implement it yourself? It wouldn't take terribly long. How performance-critical is this? Do you need to worry about surrogate pairs? (Are you happy for them to be encoded as a pair of `\u` escape sequences?)

Comment: Using the right terminology should improve your chances of finding a solution: what you want is not encoded in Unicode; it uses Java-specific Unicode escape form.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I just wanted not to re-invent a wheel. I from the answer how easy it is.

Comment: There are multiple string literal formats that use `\u` escapes, but handle aspects such as surrogates and ASCII escapes differently. If you are only generating user-readable text maybe you don't care and “any old format with `\u` in” is good enough, but if you're eg creating JSON, you'll need to use the exact rules for JSON escaping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the kind of simple code Jon Skeet had in mind in his comment:

```
final String in = "šđčćasdf";
final StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++) {
  final char ch = in.charAt(i);
  if (ch <= 127) out.append(ch);
  else out.append("\\u").append(String.format("%04x", (int)ch));
}
System.out.println(out.toString());
```

As Jon said, surrogate pairs will be represented as a pair of `\u` escapes.

Comment: That was exactly my first thought, however it depends on the context---sometimes you actually want newlines to stay newlines.

Comment: Note that since backslashes are not escaped, this encoding scheme is ambiguous and does not round-trip. eg for input `é \u00E9` the output is `\u00E9 \u00E9`.

Comment: @bobince I would not call that ambiguous since `é` and `\u00E9` are synonyms under this system.

Comment: bug:feature :: ambiguous:synonyms. If you need to know the original data from the escaped form then bug, if you don't care then feature :-)

Comment: @bobince In any case, it's not this code's fault: it's what Java specifies. Round-tripping string literals is certainly a non-goal for Java.

Answer (score 0):

#### Guava Escaper Based Solution:

This escapes any non-ASCII characters into Unicode escape sequences.

```
import static java.lang.String.format;    
import com.google.common.escape.CharEscaper;

public class NonAsciiUnicodeEscaper extends CharEscaper
{
    @Override
    protected char[] escape(final char c)
    {
        if (c >= 32 && c <= 127) { return new char[]{c}; }
        else { return format("\\u%04x", (int) c).toCharArray(); }
    }
}
```