# convert String to Unicode Byte array

Tags: java, unicode

I'm trying to get the Unicode values of a String into a Byte array.

I started to use the following code that specifying Ascii. This gave a list of numbers as you would expect.

```
byte[] bytes = null;
try {
    bytes = listOfApps.getBytes("US-ASCII");
}catch(Exception e){}
Log.e(TAG, "bytes = " + Arrays.toString(bytes));
```

```
listOfAllApps = Gallery|Camera|Contacts|Phone|Email|Messages|Settings......

bytes = [71, 97, 108, 108, 101, 114, 121, 124, 67, 97, 109, 101, 114, 97......
```

.
So I changed my code to the following to specify unicode.

```
byte[] bytes = null;
try {
    bytes = listOfApps.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
}catch(Exception e){}
Log.e(TAG, "bytes = " + Arrays.toString(bytes));
```

I still get the same output. I thought i would get an array of values that start with \u. Does anybody know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: You will always get a `byte` from a `byte[]`.

Comment: "Gallery|Camera|Contacts|Phone|Email|Messages|Settings" is all representable with codepoints < 128. What do you expect to differ between US-ASCII and UTF-8?

Comment: "convert String to Unicode Char array" There is a difference between `char` and `byte` - please update your title if you actually mean "byte array".

Comment: What do you expect to differ between US-ASCII and UTF-8? I expect an array of values like "\u00C6,\u00D8,\u00C5". Basically what i am trying to do is send a list of app names to my server like Gallery|Camera|Contacts|Phone|Email|Messages|Settings. But depending on the name of the app(Android) there could be special characters that webservices does not like. so as a workaround i thought of converting the String to unicode characters as these will send to server ok

Comment: You can find the string conversion behaviour of `byte` [in JLS Sec 5.1.11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11): "A value x of primitive type T is first converted to a reference value as if by giving it as an argument to an appropriate class instance creation expression (§15.9): ... If T is byte, short, or int, then use new Integer(x)." So it will always be formatted as a "plain old" `int`.

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28176578/convert-utf-8-unicode-string-to-ascii-unicode-escaped-string)?

Comment: Please decide what you want.  The title says you want a `Char` (char wrapper) array but the text says `Byte` (byte wrapper) array, and your code uses primitive `byte`s.  Which is it?  Also, Java character values won't all fit into `byte` primitives, so you will lose some data.

Comment: You will get the actual numeric values. '\u....' (not '/u...'!) is just a representation of a numeric value. So when you got "71", that is the same as '\u0067'.  '\u00C6' is just 198. So if you see 198, you have '\u00C6'. What had you expect the 'log' call to display the output as Unicode escapes? That was an unreasonable expectation.

Comment: @LewBloch Thank you for having the patience to explain that... it makes more sense now! My business partner said that if we sell our software in difference countries then an String(app name) could possibly have an umlout or a grave/ecute accent. Are there normal numeric Ascii values for these?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Hi i'll have a look at this later today. I think the problem i am having is not knowing how to represent umlouts and grave accents in certain languages.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
               String aStr = "gallery|settings|À ";

                 char[] charArray = aStr.toCharArray();

                 for(int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++){

                     int x = Character.codePointAt(charArray, i);
                     Log.e(TAG, "x = " + x);
                 }

x = 103
x = 97
x = 108
x = 108
x = 101
x = 114
x = 121
x = 124
x = 115
x = 101
x = 116
x = 116
x = 105
x = 110
x = 103
x = 115
x = 124
x = 192   //À
x = 32
```

Comment: Let's assume someone else wrote that and you, the asker, sees that. Would you understand what this means? Would you understand what the answerer tries to tell you? If not, then add an explanation to your answer.